# different alert messages on gridview update

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, gridview

Hello guys i am using gridview ( from obout ) on my asp.net site. When the user clicks on Edit the griview opens up and shows a template for the clicked row. In there i got a save button. When the user clicks on it i got a simple JS script that pop ups a simple alert. 
My problem is that now i need to show a different alert on different situations.
I tried putting this on the update event instead but it wont trigger :

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "PopUpWindow", popupscript, False)
```

I am trying to find how can i have full control on the alert the user will see after the update event.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle GridView's RowDataBound event,Try using this js function onclick

```
 protected void Gridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    // reference the Delete LinkButton
    LinkButton db = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[3].Controls[0];

    db.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you certain you want to delete this questionnaire?');";
 }
}
```

(OR)

See [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26115/Simple-non-JS-GridView-Delete-Confirmation)  Example